# error when i use ToList after dynamic procedure name

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, linq-to-entities

I always use to return the number of rows ,use a foreach loop.
In a part of the project I need to get a procedure with dynamic data.
Procedure code:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[abcde]
@fldStatusIdString nvarchar(max)
as
begin    
    declare @Query nvarchar(max)
    set @Query = '
    SELECT a.fldEstateId, a.fldEstateTitle, a.fldThumbnail,a.fldPrice,fldAcceptDate
    FROM    (
                SELECT dbo.tblImages.fldEstateId, dbo.tblImages.fldThumbnail, dbo.tblEstates.fldEstateTitle,
                 dbo.tblEstates.fldPrice, dbo.tblEstates.fldAcceptDate,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dbo.tblImages.fldEstateId 
                ORDER BY dbo.tblEstates.fldAcceptDate) AS RowNumber
                FROM    dbo.tblImages INNER JOIN    dbo.tblEstates ON dbo.tblEstates.fldEstateId = dbo.tblImages.fldEstateId
                WHERE   (dbo.tblEstates.fldStatusOfAccept = 1)'
                set @Query +='and (fldStatusId in('+@fldStatusIdString+'))
            ) AS a
    WHERE   a.RowNumber = 1
    order by fldEstateId        
    '        
    execute sp_executesql  @Query
end
```

When i use above procedure, can not use ToList in foreach loop.
If the normal procedure is not a problem, but if i use a above way(input data with the number of variables), I get an error.
C# Code:

```
List<Join_Estates_Images_Model> ListAll = new List<Join_Estates_Images_Model>();
foreach (var item in db.abcde(fldStatusIdString).ToList())
{
    Join_Estates_Images_Model _entity = new Join_Estates_Images_Model();
    _entity.fldEstateId = item.fldEstateId;
    _entity.fldEstateTitle = item.fldEstateTitle;
    _entity.fldThumbnail = item.fldThumbnail;
    _entity.fldPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(item.fldPrice);
    _entity.fldAcceptDate = item.fldAcceptDate;
    ListAll.Add(_entity);
}
return ListAll;
```

Error message:

```
Error    14    'int' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I used 'using System.Linq'

Comment: see your result set in entity. it defiantly a interger

Comment: are you using entity frame work ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of doing it will be to pass the comma delimited list to the variable and handle it inside the procedure something like ......

Also you do not need dynamic sql here.....

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[abcde]
@fldStatusIdString nvarchar(max)
as
begin    
  DECLARE @xml XML;

  SET @xml = N'<t>' + REPLACE(@fldStatusIdString,',','</t><t>') + '</t>';

    SELECT a.fldEstateId, a.fldEstateTitle, a.fldThumbnail,a.fldPrice,fldAcceptDate
    FROM    (
                SELECT dbo.tblImages.fldEstateId
                    , dbo.tblImages.fldThumbnail
                    , dbo.tblEstates.fldEstateTitle
                    , dbo.tblEstates.fldPrice
                    , dbo.tblEstates.fldAcceptDate
                    ,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dbo.tblImages.fldEstateId 
                                          ORDER BY dbo.tblEstates.fldAcceptDate) AS RowNumber
                FROM    dbo.tblImages 
                INNER JOIN    dbo.tblEstates 
                ON dbo.tblEstates.fldEstateId = dbo.tblImages.fldEstateId
                WHERE   (dbo.tblEstates.fldStatusOfAccept = 1)
               and (fldStatusId in(
                                   SELECT  r.value('.','varchar(MAX)') as item
                                   FROM  @xml.nodes('/t') as records(r)
                                   )
                    )
            ) AS a
    WHERE   a.RowNumber = 1
    order by fldEstateId        
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same kind of problem with entity framework. Entity framework always gives a integer resultset with dynamic query. Just follow below steps

Update your model

1. Drop your procedure from .edmx.
2. Drop result set and related function as well.
3. Update your procedure. Generate result set with non dynamic query.
4. Again add procedure in your entity.